# Swift error: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_SwiftValue encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000012abe0'

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults, nscoding

I have this error. I know some people have answered this on other threads but the answers given did not seem to work for me.

Here is my code:

The People class:

```
class People: NSObject, NSCoding {

    var firstName : String
    var lastName : String
    var events : [Event]
    init(firstName: String, lastName: String) {

        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.events = []
    }

    required init (coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
         firstName = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "firstName") as! String
        lastName = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "lastName") as! String
        events = aDecoder.decodeObject (forKey: "events") as! [Event]


    }

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(firstName, forKey: "firstName")
        aCoder.encode(lastName, forKey: "lastName")        
        aCoder.encode(events, forKey: "events")
    }

}
```

Here is where I call to save the file:

```
func SaveMyPeople(){
    let Defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let SavedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: ArrayPeople)
    Defaults.set(SavedData, forKey: "People") 
}
```

This is the Event Struct:

```
struct Event{
    var date : String
    var message : String
}
```

Any help I can get will be very much appreciated

Comment: This isn't the issue, but you're missing `super.init(coder: aDecoder)` in `required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` and also missing the `?` in the signature of that `init`.

Answer (score 3):

`NSCoding` requires the `NSObjectProtocol`. Only Classes can conform to `NSObjectProtocol` and you're using a Struct.
ie:

```
struct Event{
    var date : String
    var message : String
}
```

Soroush Khanlou wrote a nice post about this [here](http://khanlou.com/2016/10/structs-and-nscoding/)